# Change the Dialog style using a theme

Tags: java, android

I was wondering whether there is a simple way to tell Android to always use a custom style to display `Dialogs`.

Using themes and styles you can change the look and feel of all, say, `TextViews` using this piece of code when defining a theme in themes.xml:

```
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Blue.TextView</item>
```

with Blue.TextView being defined in styles.xml.

Is there some way to do so for `Dialogs` as well ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is. for example,

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyTheme);
```

or, if you are using a `DialogFragment`, just call the [setStyle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setStyle%28int,%20int%29) method,

Comment: Actually what I need to achieve is customize the prompt frame that is shown when clicking on a Spinner, not just show a Dialog with a custom style.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style
    name="Theme_Dialog_Translucent"
    parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item
        name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

Below is the working code::

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.ThemeDialogCustom);
mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); //But here It is not workin
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
```